# this is changed to undefined with webpack + typescript + module = "esnext"

Tags: typescript, webpack, tsconfig, ecmascript-next, ts-loader

I have a setup with webpack + typescript (using ts-loader).

To enable code splitting with webpack, [you must set module to esnext in tsconfig](https://www.skovy.dev/blog/code-splitting-with-webpack-typescript-react?seed=2hi2j0):

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext"
    // other configuration ...
  }
}
```

I'm trying to pass `this` as a parameter in one of my files. It works on node.js, which runs on individually compiled files using the native typescript compiler, but the problem is:

**in webpack `this` is replaced with `undefined`**

I've reduced it to this simple setup:

Typescript source code

```
export var this2 = this;
```

Output of `tsc`:

```
export var this2 = this;
```

Webpack output:

```
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./src/index.ts ***!
  \**********************/
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "this2": () => (/* binding */ this2)
/* harmony export */ });
var this2 = undefined;

/******/ })()
;
```

This even happens when there is a lot of other things exported in the file (so this is not just empty and therefor reduced to undefined)

I'm not 100% sure where the issue lies. But note that **this does *not* happen** with the same setup without typescript (so webpack + javascript source + module=esnext) *nor* does it happen with compiling typescript to javascript for nodejs with `tsc`.

I wonder where the problem lies and if this is expected behavior for any reason.

I want a file register all the exports of that file somewhere, without having to import it (the other file doesn't know of its existence). But this behavior seems to make it impossible to access the files' exports and pass them to a function

**minimal reproduction setup**

See this [live stackblitz setup](https://stackblitz.com/edit/webpack-tsloader-esnext-this-undefined?file=src%2Findex.ts&terminal=build%2Cstart)

Run `webpack` or `tsc` in the terminal to recreate the outputs in `/webpack` and `/tsc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` at the top level of an ESM module has the value `undefined`. That's per specification ([link](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-module-environment-records-getthisbinding)). So Webpack is just doing what the specification says.

If you want the value `this` would have at the top level of a non-module script, use the new(ish) `globalThis` ([spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-globalthis) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)).

In a comment (and in your question!) you've said:

> I would like to access all the files' exports like this usually does in commonjs

You can do that in a surprising way: By getting the module namespace object of the module from...itself! Say you're doing this in `mod.js`. You can get the module namespace object for the module itself by doing:

```
// *IN* `mod.js` itself
import * as mod from "./mod.js";
```

`mod` will refer to an object that has properties for all of the module's exports (the default export will have the property name `default`). Here's a complete example:

```
export const a = 42;
export const fn = () => { };

import * as mod from "./mod.js";
console.log(mod.a);        // 42
console.log(typeof mod.fn) // "function"
```

That said, if you want to pass things around as a unit like that, you might consider creating an object explicitly and exporting the object. It depends on the use case.

Comment: Thank you for that clarity. I didn't know that. How would I use `globalThis` though? If I log globalThis from the file it logs the window object. I would like to access all the files' exports like `this` usually does in commonjs

Comment: @Flion - Ah! Sorry, you did mention in the question what you were trying to do with `this` but I missed it. There's a way to do that in ESM (I've updated the answer), though you might consider writing an object instead if you want to pass it around like that.

Comment: Perfect! Very insightful. Thanks for your clear answer, exactly what I was looking for.